# Routing data via a unique field in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0

How do you set up routing to view data via a field other than the ID in CakePHP? I'm trying to view my users via `/username/'username'` in CakePHP 2.4.

So far, I have this in my **routes.php**, however I can't figure out how to pass the username to my Users controller and use that instead of an ID if needs be.

```
Router::connect(
    '/username/:username',
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('username')
    )
);
```

And my controller function, I have this, which throws a **Fatal error: Call to undefined function findByUsername()**:

```
public function view($id = null, $username = null) {

    if ($user = $this->User-findByUsername($username)) {
        $this->set('user', $user);
    } elseif ($user != $this->User-findByUsername($username)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    } else {
        if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        $options = array('conditions' => array('User.' . $this->User->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->set('user', $this->User->find('first', $options));
    }
}
```

Comment: `...User-findByUsername()` -> `...User->findByUsername()`. Otherwise, since the `findBy...` is a magic function mapping to your table columns, is your username field spelt `Username` case sensitively? `UserName` would be different...

Comment: I'd also suggest removing the `$id` argument if you aren't going to use it, or use the `$username` argument as both depending on if it is an integer or string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First solution

Don't do anything with routers. They are just fine as they are in default CakePHP package. There were couple of syntax errors in your code. This should work when called either

```
"app/controller/view/-/username"
```

or

```
"app/controller/view/id"
```

Controller action code itself like this

```
<?php
 public function view($id, $username = null) {
    if(!is_null($username)) {
      if($user = $this->User->findByUsername($username))
          $this->set('user', $user);
      elseif (count($this->User->findByUsername($username)) == 0)
          throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    else {
        if($id == '-') || !$this->User->exists($id))
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        else {
            $options = array('conditions' => array("User.{$this->User->primaryKey}" => $id));
            $this->set('user', $this->User->find('first', $options));
        }
    }
 }
?>
```

### Second solution

With only one parameter this could be done like this (personally I don't like this, it breaks straightforwardness of Cake-style to do it). Call this like this:

```
"app/controller/view/username"
```

or

```
"app/controller/view/id"
```

And controller action code itself:

```
<?php
 public function view($param) {
    if(!is_numeric($param))) { // $param is not numeric => it is username
      if($user = $this->User->findByUsername($param))
          $this->set('user', $user);
      elseif (count($this->User->findByUsername($param)) == 0)
          throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    else { // $param is numeric => it is id
        if(!$this->User->exists($param))
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        else {
            $options = array('conditions' => array("User.{$this->User->primaryKey}" => $param));
            $this->set('user', $this->User->find('first', $options));
        }
    }
 }
?>
```

Comment: That looks like it should work, but going to `/users/view/username/` throws `Error: The requested address '/users/view/admin' was not found on this server.`, while `/users/view/id/` throws `Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'User.id.id' in 'where clause'`.

Comment: @schnauss: Updated my answer, sorry for mistake.

Comment: That works! I'll see how I can modify it so it takes just an ID or a username without the - in the URL.

My one change to get that to work was to remove the ) in `$id == '-')`

Comment: @schnauss: You cant. This is built in cake. If your controller action has 2 parameters, you cant set second one without passing first one also. That is why there needs to be '-' or something else in url representing first parameter value. For in case you want to deal with one parameter, see my updated answer.